# How to read a .csv file with more than one language in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, utf-8, read.csv

I want to read a .csv file in R.

However, the .csv file contains words (specific letters) from many languages.
For example, german, polish, and greek.

Some rows of the .csv file are the following:

```
1 Zürich
2 Östra Mellansverige
3 Åland
4 Stredné Slovensko
5 Małopolskie
6 Ελλάδα
```

The first 4 rows are readable using:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "german")
```

The 5th row is readable using:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "polish")
```

However, the last row is **not** readable using:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "greek")
```

How can I read all the 6 rows containing all the necessary languages?

Noting that I use the following in order to read the .csv file:

```
read.csv("file_name.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",na.strings = "",encoding="UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

The language of the text does not matter when it comes to loading the data using `read.csv`. There is no semantics or grammar here, just the encoding of the individual characters. UTF-8 contains characters and symbols from almost all languages around the world, so you can always use it if the file was written with UTF-8 encoding in the first place. Function `Sys.setlocale` is mostly for formatting decimal points vs commas or to set time zones.

Comment: Ok, I see. So, how can I appropriately do encoding of the individual characters? Do I have to know all of them that exist in the .csv file? I think this is really difficult.